# How to test in Mockito for specific order of calls with same arguments?

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito

I want to verify the specific order in which characters to ensure that they aren't getting garbled. I tried writing it using `InOrder` but it seems not to work, or at least in Mockito 1.8.5.

```
@Test
public void inOrderTest() throws IOException{
    final String message = "Hello World!\n";

    for( char c : message.toCharArray() )
        mockWriter.write( c );

    final InOrder inOrder = inOrder( mockWriter );
    for( char c : message.toCharArray() )
        inOrder.verify( mockWriter ).write( c );
    inOrder.verifyNoMoreInteractions();
}
```

The test above fails with the message:

```
Verification in order failure:
mockWriter.write(108);
Wanted 1 time:
-> at     org.bitbucket.artbugorski.brainfuj.interpreter.InterpreterTest.inOrderTest(InterpreterTest.java:62)
But was 3 times. Undesired invocation:
-> at org.bitbucket.artbugorski.brainfuj.interpreter.InterpreterTest.inOrderTest(InterpreterTest.java:58)
```

How does one write a Mockito test for that?

---

**EDIT:** Filed as bug http://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=296

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My apologies to the previous respondents; but in my opinion, using an Answer flies a little in the face of one of the basic ideas of Mockito, namely that stubbing and verifying are two completely separate processes.  Mockito has features for stubbing and features for verification, and the makers of Mockito have made an effort to keep the two separate.  Answers are intended for stubbing; and whereas there are a few cases where an Answer is the best way to verify, I don't believe this is one of them.

I would use an ArgumentCaptor instead of an Answer.  I would write a method like this in the test class, then call it with "Hello world" as the argument.  Note that I haven't tested this, so it may contain typos.

```
private void verifyCharactersWritten( String expected ){
    ArgumentCaptor<Character> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass( Character.class ); 
    verify( mockWriter, times( expected.length())).write( captor.capture());
    assertEquals( Arrays.asList( expected.toCharArray()), captor.getAllValues());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Slick. I didn't know about that feature of the arg captor.

Comment: sometimes easily to check result/output/outcome (if it is possible) then read this test code. I mean if we know that it should return us: "some sting we expected" for given possible arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Verification in order is a separate concept from how many times something is done, so when you get to the 'l' and tell Mockito to verify that it happened, it passes the in-order check, but fails because the 'l' call was made three times, and you (implicitly) told it to expect it only one time. It's a quirk I've hit before in Mockito, but pretty much any time it happens, I end up deciding that my test is poorly written, and when I fix it, the problem goes away. In your case, I'd say it's *way* overkill to verify each character written to a Writer. If you want to verify a message got sent correctly, you should be comparing the input message to the output message. In your example, that might entail using a StringWriter instead of mocking a writer. Then the end of your test just looks like

```
assertThat(stringWriter.toString(), equalTo(message));
```

If you really have to do what you're doing, all I can suggest is digging into the Mockito code to see if there's a way to make it happen and possibly filing a bug report to see what they say about it.

Comment: I am writing a virtual machine/interpreter so I/O happens one character at a time, there is no notion of an entire message, just a series of individual characters printed to stdout. I'm trying to ensure that over the course of printing them I'm not corrupting anything (yes, I am implementing my own internal memory). The message I am trying to verify is "Hello World" so I don't think it's overkill to test that a message like that can be printed correctly, character by character. :)

Comment: Hi, well if this test is critical, ie you should test what you are emtting, I agree with @Ryan, you should prefer the comparison of the input vs the output. When stubbing your writer, use a custom answer that will append the char in a usual `StringBuilder`, then compare it to our `"Hello World"` input. Alternatively you can probably write a custom matcher; something like `inOrder.verify(mockWriter, times(11)).write(charsThatMatchInOrder("Hello World"));`, **however this test might break easily if the string changes !**

Comment: @Brice well the code snippet being emulated/interpreted is part of the test input so yes if it changes it is expected that the test would then fail.

Comment: I regret to have written this comment, how could I not think about it. You really should favor an ArgumentCaptor as David wrote in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

The reason Mockito works like that is consistency between verification in order and regular verification. Other words, if we didn't implement it this way the API would have been surprising in a different way :) You make trade offs made when trying to design a decent api.

So... the answer. Firstly, you should avoid statements like loops (or conditionals) in the test code. The reason is you care a lot for the test code clarity and maintainability! =)

If we remove the loops from the test we no longer have a use case, though... Without the use case it's hard to give an answer. David's ArgumentCaptor might not be a bad idea.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I disagree. I could unroll the loop and would have the same issue. I know this for a fact as I did that when trying to debug this. Second, if it is call InOrder but it can't quite tell in what order the calls were made isn't that a glaring violation of the principle of least astonishment?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently hacking around this with a custom Answer.

```
final List<Integer> writtenChars = new ArrayList<>();
willAnswer(
        new Answer(){
            @Override
            public Object answer( final InvocationOnMock invocation )throws Throwable {
                final int arg = (int) invocation.getArguments()[0];
                writtenChars.add( arg );
                return null;
            }
        }
    ).given( mockWriter ).write( anyInt() );
```

Then after running the desired methods I test against the expected String against the list.

```
final Iterator<Integer> writtenCharItr = writtenChars.iterator();
for( int charInt : "Hello World!\n".toCharArray() )
    assertThat(  charInt, is( writtenCharItr.next() )  );
assertThat( "There are no more chars.", writtenCharItr.hasNext(), is(false) );
verify( mockWriter ).flush();
```

Though this won't work if you are interested in more than once method call unless you record in the list which method got called etc.

---

**EDIT:** apologies to Brice you seems to have independently come to this solution except independently and better by using a `StringBuilder` instead of a `List`, though for a general case a List works better.

Comment: What was I thinking... An ArgumentCaptor is way better, it basically does what this custom answer is doing. David's response is much more correct in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird test, but still, it should be supported by the mocking API. I believe it *can* be supported by Mockito, since other mocking APIs do support it.

With *Unitils Mock*:

```
Mock<Writer> mockWriter;

@Test
public void inOrderTest() throws Exception {
    Writer writer = mockWriter.getMock();
    final String message = "Hello World!\n";

    for (char c : message.toCharArray())
        writer.write(c);

    for (char c : message.toUpperCase().toCharArray())
        mockWriter.assertInvokedInSequence().write(c);
    MockUnitils.assertNoMoreInvocations();
}
```

Or with *JMockit* (my own tool):

```
@Test
public void inOrderTest(final Writer mockWriter) throws Exception {
    final String message = "Hello World!\n";

    for (char c : message.toCharArray())
        mockWriter.write(c);

    new FullVerificationsInOrder() {{
        for (char c : message.toCharArray())
            mockWriter.write(c);
    }};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever using `inOrder`, and the same calls need to be verified with other calls in between (other method or same method with other parameters), you can use [`Mockito.calls(1)`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#calls-int-) instead of [`times(1)`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#times-int-).